# Image cache ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a Ruby on Rails way to do an image cache?

Or should I just use javascript like this:

```
test = new Image (50,50)
test.src= "/images/test.png"
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Maybe controller caching might help you:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching.html